# how to upload file to http remote server using java?

Tags: java, http, jsf, file-upload, remote-server

I need to upload images and txt files from my application to a remote server (Just http no ftp) using java. My application is in jsf framework. I searched but no suitable things found.
Can anybody guide me?
In fact I should upload files to special folder to remote server.
I have two application with shared path to upload files, so for accessing them to this files, I decidec to upload shared files(such as images and texts) to third server. First application should upload files to this remote server and second application should read them from it.
So my hard part of this solution is to upload files to this third server(in fact remote server) using http.

Comment: Everyone who suggests commons fileupload to send the file is **wrong**. It's intented to *parse* a multipart/form-data request on the other side, not to *create and send* multipart/form-data request on your side.

Comment: MAYBE the question should be made more clear. Don't expect accurate answers with a question this fuzzy!

Comment: I have two application with shared path to upload files, so for accessing them to this files, I decidec to upload shared files(such as images and texts) to third server. First application should upload files to this remote server and second application should read them from it. So my hard part of this solution is to upload files to this third server(in fact remote server) using http.

Comment: First consider following: 
1. Is an http server running on your "third server"?
2. Can you upload custom code over there?
If answer to first question is yes then answers provided below will work. 
Else first you have to install either tomcat,glassfish or some other http server overthere then work your way.

Answer (score 6):

To upload file to a specific folder, your server API must support that.

Server side for receiving uploaded files, you can use http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Client side for sending a file upload request, you can use https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: Specific folder on remote server. my application run on my server, file host isn't where my app run.

Comment: As i said, the remote server/file host must provide the API for specifying the remote destination when you upload via HTTP

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at apache [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). You can find sample code [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload).

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();//convert ur file into byte[]
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();//Client
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(YOUR_SERVER_URL);//Post Request to specified URL
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "a.txt");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);// Multipart data
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadingFile", bab); //adding data to request entity
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);//adding request entity to post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: where should I add my remote server url? In your code, what is "a.txt"? Can you explain more for me?

Comment: add ur server url in YOUR_SERVER_URL...a.txt is a file which i sent 2 server

Comment: I used your code, but nothing moved and no exception throws. Can you guide me? I changed nothing in your above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient.

Send the files using `POST` as a method.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you need to send multiple images and text files. So HTTP multi-part file upload seems to be a suitable solution. You can get further information on this from [here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).

Answer (score -4):

make

```
@Autowired
ServletContext c;
```

or take object

```
byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

String UPLOAD_FOLDEdR=c.getRealPath("/images");  
Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_FOLDEdR +"/"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
Files.write(path, bytes);
System.out.println(path);
String Pic_Name =file.getOriginalFilename();
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer so it makes sense? Currently the code is hard to read, and it's not really clear how this solves the issue in question. Please explain your answer better.