# How to uploaded and read text file in JSF and PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, readfile

I need to upload and read a text file with PrimeFaces and JSF. My question is that when I uploaded the text file, where is it stored?

Here is my `.xhtml` file:

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{send.file }" mode="simple" />
</h:form>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{send.upload}"  value="Send" ajax="false" />
```

And Java class:

```
public class Send {
    private UploadedFile file;

    public void upload() {
        if (file != null) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
}
```

I also found this example to read the file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
        {
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My other question is in this example `"C:\\testing.txt"` is given as a path? Which address I must give to read my uploaded file?

Comment: you are having the file object in upload() and use the file object then read the file line by line, using the BufferedReader

Comment: try this sample http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/file-upload-with-primefaces it will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *when I uploaded the text file, where is it stored?*

This is actually none of your business and you should not be interested in that from inside your JSF backing bean code. It's stored (partial) in memory and/or (partial) in server's temporary storage location which will be wiped/cleaned at intervals. It's absolutely not intented as permanent storage location. You should in the action/listener method just read the uploaded file content and store it in the permanent storage location to your choice.

E.g.

```
private static final File LOCATION = new File("/path/to/all/uploads");

public void upload() throws IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        String prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()); 
        String suffix = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
        File save = File.createTempFile(prefix + "-", "." + suffix, LOCATION);
        Files.write(save.toPath(), file.getContents());
        // Add success message here.
    }
}
```

Note that the `FilenameUtils` is part of Apache Commons IO which you should already have installed as it's a required dependency of `<p:fileUpload>`. Also note that `File#createTempFile()` does in above example not exactly generate a temp file, but it's just been used to generate an unique filename. Otherwise, when someone else coincidentally uploads a file with exactly the same name as an existing one, it would be overwritten. Also note that `Files#write()` is part of Java 7. If you're still on Java 6 or older, grab Apache Commons IO `IOUtils` instead.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this thread that is related to the same issue:
[how to upload file to http remote server using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719124/how-to-upload-file-to-http-remote-server-using-java).

Please if it does not help you, let me know, and I will go through. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I red the file this way

```
private UploadedFile file;

public void upload() {
    if (file != null && !"".equals(file.getFileName())) {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputstream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error uploading the file", ex);
        }
    }
}
```